# To make div visible using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below code I have a div I have set to false and I want to make visible true using jQuery. If I remove visible false in div I can make visible. Please help me to do this.

```
<div id="divmaterialconsumption" runat="server" visible="false"  ></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#<%=divmaterialconsumption.ClientID %>').show();
```

Comment: did you try to add this js in $(document).ready(function () { ... your code ..}

Comment: @Alex G My problem is If i set visible false div in design it is not working if i remove false in design i can make to visible/invisible

Comment: oh, than instead of visible="false" set style="display: none;"

Answer (score 4):

`visible="false"` on a server control (e.g. `runat="server"`) stops it being rendered at all!

Instead hide it with `style="display:none"` and get rid of the `visible="false"`

jQuery's show() method can then change the style to `display: block`

Answer (score 4):

Do the program as follows:

```
<div id="divmaterialconsumption" style="display:none;"  ></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#but1').click(function(){  //assuming event taking by click of a btn
   $('#divmaterialconsumption').css('display','block');
 });
});
```

OR

```
 $('#divmaterialconsumption').show();
```

I hope that solves your issue!